# How can i add irregular tick interval in Slider C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, slider

I've read [Microsoft's official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.slider.ticks?view=netcore-3.1) about Slider Tick, but it seems Tick is not available, i can find only Tick-frequency. how can i add irregular intervals between them? For example:

Ticks at:

```
0, 4, 5, 7, 10.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i add irregular tick interval in Slider C# UWP

I'm afraid you can't add irregular tick interval in `Slider` within UWP platform. For your requirement, we suggest you use custom `UserControl` to make irregular tick. you could use [`Manipulation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#manipulation-events) event to detect current position and calculate the matched value. then post the value with custom value change event. For `Manipulation` event please refer this official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicInput).

Comment: Can you explain a bit? or give some example link(for custom usercontrol to make irregular tick)? Because, i'm really confused how to do it. Only if Ticks was available!

Answer (score 0):

In uwp, you need to refer [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider?view=winrt-19041) about `Slider`.

If you want to get or set the increment of the value range that ticks should be created for, you can use [`Slider.TickFrequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider.tickfrequency?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Slider_TickFrequency).

For the ticks you listed, does you numbers has a common law? If yes, you can change the tick frequency in [`ValueChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase.valuechanged?view=winrt-19041) event. Otherwise, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: no, not common law, it will be irregular, like i mentioned in description. Not same intervals between each of them.

Comment: If so, can you clearify in what situation you are facing?

Comment: if the total length is 100, ticks can be at positions: 10, 40, 50, 70, 90...etc.